# Is it allowed to travel to the UK with tuberculosis that is not contagious?

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration, health

Is it valid to enter UK with tuberculosis that is not contagious and the treatment is in process?

I have a valid visa and I work there, so I need to know whether it is possible to travel back to the UK for work.

Comment: Welcome. Are you from a country which the UK requires a TB/health check to enter? If so, you may need a certificate from a UK-approved clinic about your diagnosis and treatment. Even if you are not and if diagnosis occurred after being granted a visa, you may need to provide medical reports that your disease is not in a transmissible stage (e.g., at the border as you are carrying medication, or to your employer, or the NHS)

Comment: @user88206 What is your residency status in the UK? The UK Immigration Rules Part 1 (Medical) https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-part-1-leave-to-enter-or-stay-in-the-uk state that a returning resident should not be refused leave to enter or have existing leave to enter or remain cancelled on medical grounds. Depending on the circumstances the Immigration Officer should give the person concerned a notice requiring him to report to the Medical Officer of Environmental Health with a view to further examination and any necessary treatment.

Comment: User has not returned to clarify. Putting on hold.